# AirDrop shardingd error

Tags: macos, ipad, error, airdrop

Trying to debug AirDrop issues on the mac with an iPad mini 4th gen (both up-to-date).

Basically on the Mac I can see the iPad (most of the time) and I can transfer files, however I can never see the Mac when I try to share a file (usually a picture from Photos).

I have the visibility of both iPad and Mac to Everyone and I think I have narrowed it down to the following error. However, I don't know where to go from here!!

```
08/04/2016 12:56:11.737 sharingd[269]: tcp_listener_accept Failed to set SO_NOSIGPIPE on new connection from fe80::ac13:bbff:fe88:5c69%awdl0.55701
```

Also, just as a side note, when both cannot see each other (happens quite often) I often notice that the Bonjour service doesn't seem to want to run. Anyone know how I can kick it into life?!

FYI, I have tried the basics like disable firewall (both OSX and Little snitch)...

TIA!!

Answer (score -1):

This was  problem with LittleSnitch after all. Disable the network filter and it works as expected.